# Inserting table into IFRAME using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, html-table

I was trying to insert a table in iframe when  I click a  button, but I get an error in the method "pasteHTML" .
Here is the code I wrote:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <input type = "button" onClick="setContent()" value="getContent"></input>
    <iframe id = "iframe" border="0" >
    </iframe>


  <script type="text/javascript">
   var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
    iframe.contentDocument.designMode = "on";

    function setContent()
   {

       var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
       var str = "<table><tr><td>dushyanth</td></tr></table>";
       var sel = iframe.document.selection.createRange();
       sel.pasteHTML(str);
       sel.select();


   }


  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary for you to use only java script? . This can achieved using other ways too like using .load() inside java script function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function setContent()   {
      $('divId').load('another.html')
   }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type = "button" onClick="setContent()" value="getContent"/>
  <div id="divId"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

another.html

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>xyz</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: here i am making use jQuery function .load()

Comment: does this insert table at a particular position in an iframe?

Comment: here i am not using iframe at all, i am just insert another html page containing your table into div tags in your current html page. If you want to use Iframe then you to do  some modification in above code.

Comment: The scenario is different when dealing with iframes. Can corrections be suggested to make ths work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use iframe then use following code,

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function setContent()   {
      $('divId').load('iframepage.html')
   }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type = "button" onClick="setContent()" value="getContent"/>
  <div id="divId"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

iframepage.html

```
 <html>
 <body>
<iframe width="500px" height="400" src="anotherpage.html"></iframe>
 </body>    
</html>
```

anotherpage.html

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>xyz</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ifr = document.getElementById('iframe');
ifr.src='javascript:"<table><tr><td>dushyanth</td></tr></table>"';
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3Efva/